# How to get html <td> values using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Im very new to html and javascript.

I want to get the content of  element whenever the user click on a table row using javascript.

**`test.html`**

```
<html>
<head>
<script text="text/javascript">
function dispTblContents() {
 var pName = document.getElementById("pName").value;
 var pAddress = document.getElementById("pAddress").value;
 var pEmail = document.getElementById("pEmail").value;

 alert(pName + " " + pAddress + " " + pEmail);
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
 <table>
  <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Address </th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr onclick="dispTblContents();" >
            <td id="pName">Ricardo Lucero</td>
            <td id="pAddress">Mexico City, Mexico</td>
            <td id="pEmail">rlucero@test.com</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

 </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Whenever I click the row it displays `undefined undefined undefined`. I know my code is wrong but I really don't how to fix this. Can somebody please help me. Im very new to this thing. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need `innerHTML` not `value` here, `value` is used for form elements.

```
<script text="text/javascript">
function dispTblContents() {
 var pName = document.getElementById("pName").innerHTML;
 var pAddress = document.getElementById("pAddress").innerHTML;
 var pEmail = document.getElementById("pEmail").innerHTML;

 alert(pName + " " + pAddress + " " + pEmail);
}
</script>
```

You might also want to look into jQuery if you're not using it yet, it makes selecting and manipulating HTML with Javascript a lot easier.

Comment: Using *innerText* or *textContent* (as appropriate) would be better so that markup is not returned.

Answer (score 2):

Try to change **value** to *innerHTML* or *innerText*

```
document.forms[0].getElementsByTagId("pName").innerText;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try change `value` to `innerHTML`

Answer (score 1):

A `<td>` tag doesn't have a **value**.

Use `document.getElementById("pName").innerHTML` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I searched a lot for it too. Finally I get to see teaches's solution. This is an example that works:

```
    ...........
  <head>             
        <script type="text/javascript">

        function ChangeColor(tableRow, highLight)
        {
           if (highLight){
               tableRow.style.backgroundColor = '00CCCC';
           }

        else{
             tableRow.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
            }   
      }

      function DoNav(theUrl)
      {
      document.location.href = theUrl;
      }
      </script>

    </head>

    <% ArrayList<Student> students = StudentsManager.getInstance().getStudents(); %>

    <body>
      Choose a student <br>

      <table>
          <tr>
            <td>
            <table id = "c" width="180" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

            <% for (Student st : students){ %>

            <tr onmouseover="ChangeColor(this, true);" 
                onmouseout="ChangeColor(this, false);" 
                onclick="DoNav('http://localhost:8080/Mydata/ComplexSearch/FoundC.jsp?studentId=<%=st.getStudentId()%>');">

                 <td name = "title" align = "center"><%= st.getStudentId() %></td>

            </tr>
           <%}%>

...............
```

**students** is an ArrayList that contains objects of type Student(studentId, name).
The table displays all the students. Befor you click on a cell, click view source. You'll see:

```
<tr onmouseover="ChangeColor(this, true);" 
            onmouseout="ChangeColor(this, false);" 
            onclick="DoNav('http://localhost:8080/Mydata/ComplexSearch/FoundC.jsp?studentId=1');">

             <td name = "title" align = "center">1</td>

        </tr>
```

Well in my case was "1". I didn't make the destination page yet.